# youtube embed iframe on play button not working in iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, video, youtube, embed

video opening on iPhone 7, 8, Ipad. but not working play button iPhone 6 (latest version).

iframe code :

`<iframe width="360" height="230" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7na_-LfGfpE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`